# does switching my paging file in a non system partition will slow my PC?

Tags: windows-7, paging

I have running out of space on Drive c: because of the windows 7 updates and other software. so I decided to switch my paging file from drive c: to drive D: to free some space temporally until I can get a larger hard disk.

I have noticed that my desktop delay in appearing a little. my question is "Does switch my paging file will slow my Windows?"

Comment: The reason that this is generally not a good idea to do is because your system may not boot if the page file drive is missing for whatever reason. By leaving it on the Windows partition you have one less point of failure. It is much better to move everything else to the other drive. You can use junctions to avoid re-installing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless:
 - you moved it to a much slower drive
 - you moved it to a drive that is being used intensively by other applications

Otherwise, if your C: drive is used the most (by your operating system and applications) and you are using your pagefile a lot, moving it to a different drive could in theory help reduce hard disk I/O bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to answer properly, since it heavily depends on your hardware and how it's connected.

If the other drive or partition is on the same physical drive, there shouldn't be any performance difference at all.

If it's on another physical drive, but still on the same controller/connection (using IDE), then performance might indeed be worse.

If it's on a second controller/connection (no matter whether IDE or SATA), then it should actually boost your performance (considering the new drive is at least as fast as the original one).

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/clinth/archive/2013/06/07/should-the-paging-file-be-moved-from-c-drive.aspx) has some good points and observations that will definitely help answer your question.

The short answer is it would be better to move it to a non system partition IF this partition to which it's being moved is on another disk with fairly good read/write speeds.

IF the paging file however is being moved to another partition (say D:) which is on the same volume, then you wouldn't notice any improvement in performance